# PDO prepare() error

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I've got this, error (And yes, I've searched for it, but couldn't find any solutions).

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\inetpub\oop\_classes\class.users.php on line 19
```

Class.users.php:

```
<?php
include_once("class.db.php");

class Users {

    protected $vpanel;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->vpanel = new Database();
        $this->vpanel = $this->vpanel->dbConnection();

    }

    public function Login($username, $password) {

        if(!empty($username) || !empty($password)) {

            $sth = $this->vpanel->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?");
            $sth->bindParam(1, $username);
            $sth->bindParam(2, $password);
            $sth->execute();

            if($sth->rowCount() == 1) {

                echo "Correct details.";

            } else {

                echo "Incorrect details.";

            }


        } else {

            echo "Fill out all the fields.";

        }
    }
} ?>
```

class.db.php:

```
<?php

class Database {

    public function dbConnection() {

        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbname = "DBNAME";
        $dbusername = "DBUSERNAME";
        $dbpass = "PASSWORD";

        try {

            $this->vpanel = new PDO("mysql:host".$dbhost.";dbname=".$dbname."", $dbusername, $dbpass);
            $this->vpanel->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage() . " (class.core.php) ";

        }

    }
} ?>
```

global.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/_includes/config.php";

try {

    $vpanel = new PDO("mysql:host".$Config['db']['host'].";dbname=".$Config['db']['dbname']."", $Config['db']['uname'], $Config['db']['pass']);

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/_classes/class.db.php";
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/_classes/class.users.php";

$database = new Database();
$users = new Users(); ?>
```

I don't know whats wrong, I'm new to the PDO methods (and some of the OOP)... so... thanks.

Comment: `$this->vpanel = $this->vpanel->dbConnection()` will assign `NULL` to `$this->vpanel` after `dbConnection()` finishes, since it doesn't return anything.

Comment: if you have sucessfully established a connection to your mysql database, then the query you are running is returning a false, hence the failure

Comment: By the way, get rid of this try..catch stuff. it is useless and error prone here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dbConnection is not returning anything. You need to have it return $this->vpanel so that Users->__construct can assign it to the class variable.

```
public function dbConnection() {

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "DBNAME";
    $dbusername = "DBUSERNAME";
    $dbpass = "PASSWORD";

    try {

        $this->vpanel = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpass);
        $this->vpanel->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $this->vpanel;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage() . " (class.core.php) ";
        return false;
    }
}
```

And your Login function:

```
public function Login($username, $password) {

    if($this->vpanel === false){
        echo "There is no database connection.";
        return false;
    }

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

        $sth = $this->vpanel->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?");
        $sth->bindParam(1, $username);
        $sth->bindParam(2, $password);
        $sth->execute();

        if($sth->rowCount() == 1) {

            echo "Correct details.";

        } else {

            echo "Incorrect details.";

        }


    } else {

        echo "Fill out all the fields.";

    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the only cause for a prepare() fail

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in C:\inetpub\oop\_classes\class.users.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\oop\_classes\class.users.php(21): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\inetpub\oop\index.php(10): Users->Login('d', 'd') #2 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\oop\_classes\class.users.php on line 21

Comment: Frankly, I'm surprised you're not getting the error on your catch inside of dbConnection. I've modified the `new PDO` line so that it should actually connect to the database. I also added a check inside of your Login function to check that the database connection exists.

Comment: The fact that it's saying 'No database selected' is interesting. Check to make sure you're using a correct database name on your PDO Connection.

Comment: Fixed it. I forgot the "=" after host.